# Java scanner - allowing a certain number of ints

Tags: java

Really struggling to find the answer to this.

I'm creating a game where it asks how many players there are and the max number of players the user can enter is 3 (either 1, 2 or 3).  Is this creating a for loop or can I just enter a parameter in the scanner function?

**Code below:**

```
System.out.println(" How many players are there? ");

int numberOfPlayers = scan.nextInt();

Player[] players = new Player[numberOfPlayers]; //this is where the players scores are stored
int currentPlayer = 0;  //because arrays start at 0: +1 is added

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {

    System.out.println("What is player " + (i + 1) + " called?");
    String playerName = scan.next();
    players[i] = new Player(playerName);
```

Comment: I  would use a `do/while` loop, to loop until you have a valid number.

Comment: Thank you for the answers so far however none seem to be working.  The do/ try loops by YCF_L work however when I progress to the next part where I'm required to enter the players names, I'm only able to enter 1 name before the following errors occur: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Game.go(Game.java:70)
 at Game.main(Game.java:14)

Comment: This error means you are trying to access an element of an array which is out side the bounds i.e. your array is empty.  When you step through the code in your debugger, can you see why it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)'s [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) which reads the newline instead of `next()` as shown below:

```
    System.out.println(" How many players are there? ");
    int numberOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    Player[] players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        System.out.println("What is player " + (i + 1) + " called?");
        String playerName = scan.nextLine();
        players[i] = new Player(playerName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())` with a loop for example :

```
int numberOfPlayers = 0;
boolean correct = false;
do {
    try {
        System.out.println(" How many players are there? ");
        numberOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if (numberOfPlayers >= 1 && numberOfPlayers <= 3) {
            correct = true;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
} while (!correct);
```

So if the user enter incorrect number or a number `> 3` or `< 1` it will ask the user to enter the number again until the the user enter the correct number `1,2,3`